# How to dynamically move segments in pie chart

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, pie-chart

[image]

Suppose this is a pie chart i want to increase the blue area by moving one segment of it dynamically by using the mouse.How do i start off with this.Please help

Comment: Javascript? is it a winform or wpf?

Comment: web application havent tried javascript i am new to it